# VS 2005, SQL 2008, KB954961 Won't Install - Win7 x64 Issue?

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2005, windows-7

I recently installed Win 7 x64 on my machine. I have Visual Studio 2005 Standard, and need to install the update for SQL 2008 support, so I can connect to the remote SQL Server within VS.

http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=E1109AEF-1AA2-408D-AA0F-9DF094F993BF&displaylang=en

When I try to run the update, I get this message:

The upgrade patch cannot be installed by the Windows Installer service because the program to be upgraded may be missing or the upgrade patch may update a different version of the program. Verify that the program to be upgraded exists on your computer and that you have the correct upgrade patch.

I have verified that VS has SP 1 installed, and have even tried reinstalling it.

I am wondering if the problem could be that I'm on Windows 7 64bit? Has anyone had this issue?

Answer (score 1):

The update you are trying to install requires Visual Studio 2005 SP1 Professional Edition or Visual Studio 2005 SP1 Team System Edition.  Standard edition cannot apply the update...

Please see the system requirements section on the [Microsoft support page](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/954961).

Sorry it's not working for you...sounds like a lot of frustration.

Comment: Ok, I can switch to Pro or Team. I will try that. Thank you!

Comment: I switched to Pro, and everything is fine. The update page itself only mentions VS, but I see that the KB article actually does specify Pro or Team editions. Thank you very much for your answer!