# Visual Studio 2005 Reporting Services with SQL Server 2008

Tags: visual-studio, sql-server-2008, reporting-services, visual-studio-2005

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Visual Studio 2005 doesn't support Sql Server 2008](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1593345/visual-studio-2005-doesnt-support-sql-server-2008)

I've got an issue with my Visual Studio Reporting Service where sometimes when I open reports, which are working in Reporting Services, for editing and I get an error which says:

> "The server version is not supported. You must have Microsoft SQL server 2005 Beta 2 or later"

This started to occur when we started using a new SQL Server 2008.
Anyway what I'm asking is - is it possible to upgrade to a new Visual Studio while keeping all reports intact, updated and editable?

Also isn't SQL Server 2008 able to work with Visual Studio 2005?

Comment: don't use the words like 'versus' in post title

Comment: Visual studio is used to build and design the report. Apologies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you cannot work with SQL Server 2008 RS from Visual Studio 2005. You need to install Visual Studio 2008 instead. I strongly recommend don't stuck with so old software.

Also Microsoft usually brings backward compatibility: you can work with SQL Server 2005 from Visual Studio 2008 but not vise versa.

And yes, you can upgrade SSRS 2008 to SSRS 2008 keeping all the data. But backup it first anyway .

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to add to this a handy workaround I found if you're in a particular situation.  You can actually use Visual Studio 2005 and create SSRS 2005 reports and still pull from SQL 2008 data.  This can be done as long as you have one server in your environment running SQL 2005 still.

You just need to create a linked server for your 2008 servers.  Then, in SSRS, you create one data source to your 2005 server, but reference the 2008 linked server in your query, and it'll work.  For example, if you have a SQL 2008 server called Chicago and a SQL 2005 server called Detroit, you'd create a linked server on Detroit for Chicago, and you'd create a data source in Visual Studio 2005 for your report that would point to Detroit.  Then, in your query, you'd just have something like SELECT * FROM Chicago.Database.dbo.Table and it should work.

Obviously you'll probably want to switch to a 2008 environment altogether, but this is a nice thing to know for the conversion phase.

Hope that helps.